# How to get the type of an object which data has passed by user

Tags: python-3.x, types, user-input

I taking input from user in python, How to know user has passed int or string or float etc??

```
number1 = eval(sys.argv[1])
number2 = eval(sys.argv[2])
```

if user passed input is float or int, i want to sum them, but how to know which type of data user passed? because all data which user passes is default type is string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use eval() for that,

```
import sys


def main():
    number1 = eval(sys.argv[1])
    number2 = eval(sys.argv[2])
    print(number1 + number2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when the user enters an integer as an input the input() function returns a string, but in the case of eval() it will evaluate the returned value from a string to an integer, same in float . No need to check data type every time.

see 3rd number of below link,

https://towardsdatascience.com/python-eval-built-in-function-601f87db191

Answer (score 0):

There are built in methods for that:

```
int()
str()
```

for example convert, if possible, while `type()` tells you what it is:

```
x = "Hi there"
print(type(x))

y = 3
print(type(y))
y = str(y)
print(type(y))
```

When receiving user input, you can try converting it and if successful, work with the result of the conversion:

```
_in = input("Some input please  ")

try:
    _in = int(_in)
except:
    try:
        _in = float(_in)
    except:
        pass

print(_in)
print(type(_in))

>>Some input please  3
>>3
>><class 'int'>

>>Some input please  3.5
>>3.5
>><class 'float'>
```

Comment: But user input is by default string in python3, then how to know user entered string value or int or float value..

Comment: You can try converting it, and if successful, work with the result. I'll update my answer.

Comment: if input is string then ?? all time i have to apply if else??

Comment: Well... yes. The input doesnt magically become not a string based on its intrinsic values. You can do what I did above (it should work well enough for when you require specifically a numer as input), or you can use `re` to match input strings with regex instead, but that will be just as, if not more complex in terms of logic switches (á la if/else, try/except etc)

Answer (score 0):

Python advocates the approach of "ask forgiveness, not permission". All user input is probably going to be a string - especially if you're getting it from `sys.argv` - but the best way to determine this is to attempt to make them numbers (using `try`/`except`) and then revert to different behavior if that fails.

```
num1str, num2str = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
try:
    # might as well do float, because every valid integer that can be represented in a 
    # string is also a valid float
    num1 = float(num1str)
    num2 = float(num2str)
    num3 = num1 + num2
except ValueError:  
    # this happens if the variable cannot be converted, e.g. the user entered something
    # that cannot be interpreted as a float
    ...
```

Comment: "every valid integer...is also a valid float" but worth pointing out not with the same precision.  Python floats lose precision at around 16 decimal digits.  `float('12345678901234567') != int('12345678901234567')`, for example.